# duplicate record and add variable

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in Access that looks just like this.

```
ORDNO   OPSEQ   OPDSC                   UU40MX
M438840 0010    TURN COMPLETE           2                                       
M438840 0020    BROACH SPLINE           1                                       
M438840 0030    FINAL INSPECT           1                                       
M438840 0040    WASH, OIL, PACK         1
```

What needs to happen is for there to be an extra record copied when UU40MX > 1 and change the OPSEQ to Count by letters. Basically I want to look like this.

```
ORDNO   OPSEQ   OPDSC                   UU40MX
M438840 0010a   TURN COMPLETE           2 
M438840 0010b   TURN COMPLETE           2                                      
M438840 0020    BROACH SPLINE           1                                       
M438840 0030    FINAL INSPECT           1                                       
M438840 0040    WASH, OIL, PACK         1
```

The Problem is that I know next to nothing about SQL or access and every where I go to look is far above me. If any one can help me out that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: You are in trouble to do this with SQL in access. Best advice I can give you is to do it in a programming language of your choice.

Comment: Are you trying to fix the data in a single pass, or is this going to be an ongoing issue?

Comment: it is an ongoing issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Jorge suggests, need to use programming language, such as VBA. VBA can run some SQL action statements (UPDATE, INSERT) but SQL alone will not do what you want. Code would open recordset object, loop through records, run SQL actions, like:

```
Sub FixData()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, X As Integer, Z As Integer, intC As Integer, intAsc As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE UU40MX > 1 AND NOT OPSEQ LIKE '*[a-b]';")
If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    intC = rs.RecordCount
    For X = 1 To intC
        intAsc = 98
        For Z = 1 To rs!UU40MX - 1
            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1(OrdNo, OPSEQ, OPDSC, UU40MX) " & _
                "VALUES('" & rs!OrdNo & "', '" & rs!OPSEQ & Chr(intAsc) & "', '" & rs!OPDSC & "', " & rs!UU40MX & ")"
            intAsc = intAsc + 1
        Next
        rs.Edit
        rs!OPSEQ = rs!OPSEQ & Chr(97)
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

This code assumes UU40MX will never be greater than 26.